# Swipe + Tabbed Navigation for Android 2.3 and above

Tags: android, user-interface, navigation, tabbed

The quora app for android works smoothly and displays a classic tabbed+swipe interface. I need a help in implementing an app like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this out, i've played with this in the past and it works well:

https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

Comment: I need your help in changing the contents of each tab. I am using the Tabs with Icon layout. The content is string of repeated text. Please tell me how to set it to xml layouts.

Comment: this really belongs being posted as a new question, even if only for the reason that i can't properly comment code in here.

Comment: if you start a new question link me to it and i will help

Comment: Please help me with this question. http://stackoverflow.com/q/17503468/2546804